# AT & T network blocks my website which is hosted in godaddy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, ipv6, amazon-route53

My Website is https://alternavisit.net/ (Used as iframe in alternavisit.com/login) blocked when accessing from AT&T network. It says "This site cannot be reached". When i use other networks its working fine. Please help me to find the solutions.

Comment: Interesting, I can duplicate this behavior. I get `curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake` when tethered to an AT&T iOS device.

Comment: Tagged this as IPv6 because the IPv6 configuration of that site is screwed up. I tested both the addresses of the site from two different networks, and got RST on every connection attempt. In particular it will be inaccessible from all networks using NAT64. That sounds like a very likely reason for your problems.

Comment: I have checked our site in http://validador.ipv6.br/index.php?site=www.alternavisit.net&lang=en and we got the message like **"The server does not responds to a HEAD requisition. This is the most important test, this site is not accessible over IPv6!"**. Is this what you mentioned to check with IPv6.

Comment: @EswaranArumugam It is worse than that. The broken AAAA records will prevent some clients from even falling back to legacy IPv4 connectivity.